# React converting getInitialState (ES5) to this.state (ES6) with a property and method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have issue with converting my react code to new format. Can you help me.
Now I have

```
function getStateFromFlux() {
    return {
        ...
    };
}
const TasklistsPage = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            ...getStateFromFlux(),
            isCreatingTaskList: false
        };
    },
....
    _onChange() {
        this.setState(getStateFromFlux());
    }
});
```

I want smth like this one. But I have an error from my api request "error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at TasklistsPage.render"

```
function getStateFromFlux() {
    return {
        taskLists: TaskListsStore.getTaskLists()
    };
}

export default class TasklistsPage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      func: getStateFromFlux(),
      isCreatingTaskList: false
    };
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
  }
  ....
  render() {
        ...

        return (
          ...
          {
           this.state.taskLists.map(list =>
              <ListItem
               key={list.id}
               leftIcon={<FolderIcon />}
                primaryText={list.name}
               onClick={router.history.push.bind(null, `/lists/${list.id}`)}
               />
            )
          }
          ...
        )
    }
    _onChange() {
          this.setState({func:getStateFromFlux()});
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why did you replace the object spread syntax with a property? `...getStateFromFlux(),` and `func: getStateFromFlux(),` obviously don't do the same, and will lead to your `state` not having a `.taskLists` property.

Comment: Because I have tried `this.state = getStateFromFlux()` and `this.setState(getStateFromFlux());` on ES6. This variant is working without spread, but I need to add new property to the state.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to just keep the object literal as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
export default class TasklistsPage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      func: getStateFromFlux(),
      isCreatingTaskList: false
    };
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
  }
```

Try doing

```
export default class TasklistsPage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...getStateFromFlux(),
      isCreatingTaskList: false
    };
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
  }
```

In the first case, you simply assigned the return value of *getStateFromFlux()* to the key *func*. So your tasklist was under *this.state.func.taskList*. By doing a spread with the function, it will just place the contents of the object it created within the object you pass it into. You can alternatively just do the . operator on the return value from the *getStateFromFlux()* function.

In your onChange I would advise doing the same, you are assigning it to the variable named func in your code.

```
_onChange() {
      this.setState({ ...getStateFromFlux() });
}
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/components/TasklistsPage.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (35:6) there ...getStateFromFlux(),

Comment: Did you change anything else about your Babel configuration? If that worked before it should work now, but it does require some non-default Babel settings.

Comment: You can just do this.state = { taskLists: getStateFromFlux().taskLists, isCreatingTaskList: false} if you can't get babel working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's help me